# Chi-squared and T distribution when s.d isn't 1

Tags: t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

[image]

I have answered the first question but I have no clue where to start with b) and c). I'm pretty sure b) looks like the chi-squared distribution but am not sure how to work anything out as the standard deviation of the normal distributed X values is 4?

Comment: How would you do it when the SD would be equal to 1?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus does SD impact the values of the tables?

Comment: Did it have an impact for question a?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I used Z values for question a so I am not sure

Comment: Hint: $Z_i=X_i/4\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$ Use (simple) algebra to re-express each event in terms of the $Z_i.$

Answer (score 0):

(b) By simulation with a million iterations, assuming normal $\sigma = 4,$ we can expect about three significant digits of accuracy. [Sampling and
computation in R.]

```
set.seed(131)
x1 = rnorm(10^6, 0, 4)
x2 = rnorm(10^6, 0, 4)
x3 = rnorm(10^6, 0, 4)
x4 = rnorm(10^6, 0, 4)
q = x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2
quantile(q,.99)
     99% 
211.7721
```

So, if $Q = \sum_{i=1}^4 X_i^2,$ then
$P(Q \le 211.8) \approx 0.99.$

But $Q/16 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=4),$
so $P(Q/16 \le h) = P(Q \le 16h) = 0.99,$ where $h= 13.2767$ and $16h = 212.4273.$

```
qchisq(.99, 4)  # Look in printed chi-sq CDF table.
[1] 13.2767
```